# Скрытая загрузка файлов на облако

Tags: php, yii2, google-drive

Задача состоит вот в чем.

На сайте есть пользователи и разные проекты. Для каждого проекта и каждого пользователя своя папка с файлами. В этих папках так же могут быть архивы большого размера (пару гб). Таких архивов может быть много. Пользователь может загружать и скачивать эти архивы с облака. Но доступ к ним нужно регулировать. Нужно чтобы лично я с помощью кода определял, кто может скачивать или загружать файлы, а кто нет.

Какое облако позволяет загружать и скачивать файлы при этом не запрашивая доступ к аккаунту у самого пользователя? Или же как обойти доступ к аккаунту на том же Google Drive, чтобы пользователь даже не подозревал что эти файлы хранятся на облаке.

Comment: Подключаться через свою учётную запись. Тащить файл и передавать его пользователю. Получится прокси

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается Google Drive API поддерживает такую возможность. Необходимо:

1. Создать сервисный аккаунт [тут](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials)
2. Скачать библиотеку для работы с google api [тут](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client), там есть [примеры](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/master/examples) готовых решений
3. Вникнуть в документацию Google Drive API v3 об управлении файлами [тут](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)
4. Вникнуть в документацию Google Drive API v3 об управлении доступом к файлам [тут](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing)